# How to use binded data as function input in polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer

In my dom-moule, I would like to use the bound data `ticket.start_time` as an input to a function and display the function return (which is the time lapsed from `ticket.start_time` to now).

Right now, I only know how to access the bound data as follows

```
  <li><span>{{ticket.start_time}} has lapsed</span>
```

The missing part is

- how to access `ticket.start_time` from a function
- how to trigger this function

The full code is here:

```
<dom-module id="todo-app">                                                         
<template>                                                                       
<ul>      
  <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[reply.tickets]]" as="ticket">               
  <style>                                                                      
    span[done]{                                                                
      text-decoration: line-through;                                           
    }                                                                          
  </style>                                                                     
  <li><span done$={{ticket.end_time}}>{{ticket.id}}: {{ticket.detail}}, {{ticket.start_time}} has lapsed</span>
  </template>
</template>
</ul>

<iron-ajax                                                                  
  auto=true                                                                 
  id="requestData"                                                          
  url="/data"                                                               
  handleAs="json"                                                           
  on-response="handleResponse">                                             
</iron-ajax>                                                                
</template>                                                                   

  <script>                                                                      
    Polymer({                                                                   
      is: "todo-app",                                                           
      properties: {                                                             
        reply: {                                                                
          type: Object                                                          
        }                                                                       
      },                                                                        
      handleResponse: function (data){                                          
        this.reply= data.detail.response;                                       
      }                                                                         
    });                                                                         
  </script>                                                                     
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
<span>{{myFunc(ticket.start_time)}}</span>
...
<script>
  myFunc:function(item){
    //some code
    return value
 }
```